# is it allowed and possible to provide user upload videos to youtube?

Tags: video, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to create video upload for my website ,can I do some trick like provide upload video button and when user clicked button video will upload to youtube?(because I heard that storing video on server is not good idea)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely do this - Google provide an API and documentation to support video upload from your site, or from your server.

See this page and click on the Javascript example about half way down the page:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

I won't reproduce the code here as it better to look a the google API documentation as it does change sometimes.